# Tool, API of or code samples for calculating spatial similarity between Lines

Tags: postgis, vector, line, comparison

I am migrating a database with a road network to an other external data provider.
We have joined our own data about roadworks, temporary speed-limits, etc., using ID and linear referencing on this data. So I need to find the same segment in the newer dataset and its ID to migrate the data.

There are small spatial differences and no matching attributes between these to datasets, so I can't use a regular spatial join. Parallel streets close to each other make using buffers a problem.

I looking for a way to find the similarity between lines, similar to fuzzy string searching with text. This way I can find the closest matching line, add the new ID, and recalculate the lengths in our tables.

Is there a tool, API, or codesamples (I prefer Python, JavaScript or PostGIS-SQL) that shows how to do this?

Comment: ST_Difference? http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html